# Is there a way to jump to mark in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Is there a way to jump to mark in Sublime Text?

By mark, I mean under Edit, there is a selection of actions with respect to a marked line.

I need to jump between 2 or 3 places in a large file (which makes scrolling very time consuming). But I also need to be able to do that sporadically over the space of many hours (in between focusing on other things) or even days. The positions of the places may change a little. These make memorizing line numbers rather impractical. Hence it would be nice if there is a way to jumped to a marked position.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a perfect answer to what you asked for, but I can tell you my way of dealing with the problem, which might be helpful to you.

For me, long files often consist of many functions or classes. In **sublime** "Key Bindings" section there is a shortcut for "**fold_all**", which I mapped to <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. When I open a file full of classes and functions, I click this shortcut and all the classes and functions collapse to one line for each (your cursor should not be inside of any function/class before you hit the shortcut). This way the file becomes artificially much much shorter, so it's easier to go back and forth between distant places.