# Is there a way to set 'jump points' in VSCode?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

Very similar to this question:

[Is there a way to jump to mark in Sublime Text?](https://superuser.com/questions/1694898/is-there-a-way-to-jump-to-mark-in-sublime-text)

But I'm asking for VSCode.

Say I'm in a file:

```
const a = {
   a: "1", 
   b: "2",  
   // <-- I'm editing here 
}



const processThing = (thing) => {
   
  if (thing.a) {
 
  }
  // <-- I'm also editing here 
 
}
```

I'm constantly between two parts of the file. Is there a keyboard-only way to jump between these two points?

Answer (score 0):

There are extensions to do this.

See this Stack Overflow answer:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179571/are-there-bookmarks-in-visual-studio-code#:~:text=%E2%80%93%20Edit%3A%20Found%20out%20how%20to,J%20to%20jump%20to%20it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179571/are-there-bookmarks-in-visual-studio-code#:%7E:text=%E2%80%93%20Edit%3A%20Found%20out%20how%20to,J%20to%20jump%20to%20it).

I'm finding this one pretty good.

https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-bookmarks/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Look at the section Side by Side Editing in [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface)

It seems perfect for your case.

- Split the editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>
- Jump between editors using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>
- It remembers the cursor position in both editors